# ¿Cómo estructurar proyecto angular desde UML?

Tags: angular6, uml

Tengo que hacer un proyecto donde muestre una notificación Toast ya sean custom o usando la librería ngx-toastr, Eso lo entiendo.

Lo que no entiendo es como debo estructurar el proyecto según este modelo UML.

Espero que alguno de ustedes me pueda dar una mano con esto.

Se los agradezco.

Dejo imagen UML.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]